# Web API: Content in HttpResponseMessage

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse, mediatypeformatter

In one of my Get request, I want to return an HttpResponseMessage with some content. Currently I have it working as follows:

```
var header = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml");
Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, myObject, header);
```

However, since I am using the static Request, this becomes really difficult to test. From what I have read, I should be able to do the following:

```
return new HttpResponseMessage<T>(objectInstance);
```

However, seem to not be able to do this. Is it because I am using a older version of WebApi / .NET?

---

On a side note, I found that you could potentially create a response as follows:

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
response.Content = new ObjectContent(typeof(T), objectInstance, mediaTypeFormatter);
```

What puzzled me is why do I have to add a mediaTypeFormatter here. I have added the media type formatter at the global.asax level.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to pass the formatter because otherwise ObjectContent would need to use a static member to access the global collection, which would make testing harder.

Comment: Request is not static, it is an instance member of ApiController.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`HttpResponseMessage<T>` was removed after Beta. Right now, instead of a typed `HttpResponseMessage` we have a typed `ObjectContent`

If you manually create `HttpResponseMessage` using its default parameterless constructor, there is no request context available to perform content negotiation - that's why you need to specify the formatter, or perform content negotiation by hand.

I understand you don't want to do that - so use this instead:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse<MyObject>(HttpStatusCode.OK, objInstance);
```

That would create the response message relying on the content negotiation performed against the request.

Finally, you can read more about content negotiation here [On this link](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/07/everything-you-want-to-know-about-asp-net-web-api-content-negotation/)

Comment: I miss the HttpResponseMessage<T>, I think it was a better API, but Request.CreateResponse<T> work fine.

Comment: Remember that any controller method that uses `HttpResponseMessage` is very difficult to unit-test, so it's best to avoid using it if you can.

Comment: @RoyDictus I'm curious as to why it makes unit testing difficult, could you elaborate please?

Comment: Because you can not cast `HttpContent` into the type of the object that values you might want to assert.

Comment: Thanks @Filip...not exactly what I needed but it pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @Roy-Dictus Not really sure why you'd say it's very difficult to unit test. Simply check to see if the response.Content is of type ObjectContent and its Value property is of the type you expect to get. A helper method can do this in 4 lines of code. If anything, it's annoying, but certainly not 'very difficult'...

Comment: thanks, its work me, Request.CreateResponse("pass iqueryable object")

Comment: I'm missing HttpResponseMessage<T> as well as I need to read the method code to see what does the controller returns in the content :(