# How to get an object from the HttpResponseMessage?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Post method that returns an `HttpResponseMessage`:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = 
    Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, updatedItemDto);
```

I'm writing some tests for this and would like to get the updated item from the `HttpResponseMessage` (particularly the `ItemId`).  I tried inspecting the object and it looks like the object lives in `Response.Content`, but I don't know how to get it from the `Content`.

Comment: Can you access the [Content property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.content.aspx)? What is the return being use for?

Comment: Yes I can.  The return is in a test which will take the Item's ItemID and update some values.

Comment: Because .Content is not an <Item>

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.  Would you mind putting this in an answer so I can check it off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inspect the response in the debugger since you mention "it looks like the object lives in Response.Content".

You might need to cast it to something meaningful, like in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12564716/1250033),

```
Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, updatedItemDto) as MyObject;
```

Answer (score 5):

If HttpResponseMessage contain serialized data model of a known class then you can use `ReadAsAsync<>()` extension method like this

```
 MyObject obj = await response.ReadAsAsync<MyObject>();
```

And this is the most simple and easy way.

Comment: what do you mean by  'proper' ?

Comment: A known data model (class)

Comment: I believe this is now: `response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyObject>()`