# Correct return type for validation errors

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I need to implement validation in my web api controller.
In my class I have a method like this:

```
public MyEntity Post(MyEntity entity)
{
   // ...
}
```

In POST and PUT methods I usually return the created/updated object.

In [this tutoral](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api) they are returning a `HttpResponseMessage` so that they can do something like this:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // Do something with the product (not shown).

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
else
{
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
}
```

Is there a way to use a similar approach returning the saved entity?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web API: Content in HttpResponseMessage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563576/web-api-content-in-httpresponsemessage)

Comment: Good question however the title and first line suggest it is related to validation. I dont see how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateResponse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh969056(v=vs.108).aspx) method. For example:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // Do something with the product (not shown).

    return Request.CreateResponse<MyEntity>(HttpStatusCode.OK, entity);
}
```