# authentication filter: How to do a HTTP 401 with message

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api

I followed http://bitoftech.net/2014/12/15/secure-asp-net-web-api-using-api-key-authentication-hmac-authentication/ to do a custom authentication filter.

Everything is working correctly but I cannot get the server to say anything upon a 401. It correctly gives the `www-authenicate` header and status code 401 but no content/body.

I tried using `AuthenticationFailureResult` the from http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters but did not help. I converted my `AuthenticateAsync` to `async` and ignored the `await` warning.

This is my current work around, the code in comments is what I -wish- I could do, that is mostly have it use whatever formatter

```
//request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, new { Error = true, Message = "Token is invalid" });
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("{ \"Error\" = true, \"Message\" = \"Token is invalid\" }");
context.ErrorResult = new UnauthorizedResult(new AuthenticationHeaderValue[0], request);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There two options to do this: quick but brute and longer but more elegant

A. Modify HttpResponse directly:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 401;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("some content");
```

B. Implement `IHttpActionResult` and set a `Content` property of a `HttpResponseMessage` in that class:

```
public class AuthenticationFailureResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    public AuthenticationFailureResult(object jsonContent, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        JsonContent = jsonContent;
        Request = request;
    }

    public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; private set; }

    public Object JsonContent { get; private set; }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(Execute());
    }

    private HttpResponseMessage Execute()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        response.RequestMessage = Request;
        response.Content = new ObjectContent(JsonContent.GetType(), JsonContent, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
        return response;
    }
}
```

Then you'll be able to use it like this:

```
context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult(new { Error = true, Message = "Token is invalid" }, request);
```

Note: If you want to use anonymous types for `JsonContent` make sure that `AuthenticationFailureResult` implemented in the same library.

Comment: This seems like the hacky way, as it doesn't use my JSON parser. My attempt was `request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, new { Error = true, Message = "Token is invalid", });` but I can't get it to work.

Comment: There is a `AuthenticationFailureResult` class in an example from your second link.  If you have implemented IActionResult like in that example you can set  `Content` property of `HttpResponseMessage` class there in `Execute()` method.

Comment: This did not give me any output when I set the Content property

Comment: This did not give me JSON output when I set the Content property. I have to use Content = new StringContent which bypasses the JSON formatter, so setting content directly isn't what I want.

Comment: Yeah, It's really puzzling. I found this topic though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563576/web-api-content-in-httpresponsemessage. It says that content should be set with `MediaTypeFormatter`  like this: `response.Content = new ObjectContent(typeof(T), objectInstance, mediaTypeFormatter);`

Comment: That put me in the right direction, finally I was able to do `Content = new ObjectContent(jsonContent.GetType(), jsonContent, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())` Which was able to render `jsonContent` given I passed it correctly to the `AuthenticationFailureResult` class. If you could readvise your answer to account for this, I will mark it as accepted with bounty.

Comment: I'm glad that this helped. Give me an hour and I'll update the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to attach a message along with the 401 response, I think you should do it like this. This is how I did in my project:

```
public class TokenAuthenticationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // Do your authentication here
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("actionContext", "Null actionContext");
        }

        actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        actionContext.Response.Headers.Add("AuthenticationStatus", "NotAuthorized");
        actionContext.Response.ReasonPhrase = "Authentication failed";

        // Create your content here (I use Student class as an example)
        actionContext.Response.Content = new ObjectContent(
            typeof (Student),
            new Student("Forte", 23),
            new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
    }
}
```

Student class:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Student(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

Then, I use it like this:

```
[TokenAuthentication]
public class DocumentController : ApiController
{
    // Your code here
}
```

**EDIT!!!**

Thanks to `wal` suggestion in the comment, here is a shorter way of attaching message to the response:

```
actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
                new {Error = true, Message = "Token is invalid"});
```

Then, your response message will be:

```
{"$id":"1","error":true,"message":"Token is invalid"}
```

By doing this way, you don't have to set `actionContext.Response.Content` anymore.

Comment: pls note to return JSON instead of `StringContent` you can use `actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(new {Error = true, Message = "Token is invalid"});`

Comment: that edit isnt much better really. pass your object into the `Request.CreateResponse` call (or use an anon class). you dont need `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` - if you do it my way then it will honor what was requested by the callee in the `Accept` header

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it. Could you suggest a better way? :)

Comment: can you see this line that you wrote? `actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);`
replace that with what i wrote in my first comment, and then delete this line `actionContext.Response.Content...`

Comment: I can't, it shows me error because the first argument must be a `HttpStatusCode`.

Comment: try`actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, new { Error = true, Message = "Token is invalid" })`

Comment: `context.Response` doesn't exist in the scope of `AuthenticateAsync` because it takes in a context of type `HttpAuthenticationContext`

Comment: I was able to have it use `context.ActionContext.Response`  but setting that to `context.ActionContext.Request.CreateResponse` or `context.Request.CreateResponse` does not output anything. It would seem upon setting `ErrorResult` it ignores the actioncontext. You have to use the official way of setting error output as with my example of `AuthenticationFailureResult` (A google of that class name yields many people using it) but it I cannot get it to work.